# Credit Card Sized BT receiver, circuitry, eink display and power supply. Possible?

Tags: bluetooth

New to this forum. Read a bunch of replies to other 'like' questions, seems a lot of you know your stuff. Forgive me if this has already been postulated (don't think it has).

Curious to see if you can fit a BT receiver, the circuitry required to 'deal with the data' and rewrite the magstrip, a power source and possibly an e-ink display into something the size of a credit card (width/height - not necessarily thick).

Essentially, looking to be able to send mag strip rewrite commands to the card via BT from a cell phone or other BT enabled device that has the information required to the 'device' I am trying to assemble. The BT chip only has to be able to receive, not send any info. The magnetic strip has to be credit card thin, but the rest of the device, can be a little thicker.

I know I am reaching here, but would it be possible to also fit an e-ink display, 24 characters wide on the device as well, displaying certain, identifiable information required at the time of usage?

Comment: This might be better to split up. One question on the BT circuitry and a separate one on the mag strip rewrite. Those are independent issues. Also what have you looked into? And remove the e-ink question, that appears to be a shopping questions. Those are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Something 2-3mm thick is pretty feasible. Various people have done similar things as "electronic business cards" or "programmable badges".

E-ink is a bit of a pain as it requires suprisingly high voltages compared to 1.8V logic. Normally done with a boost converter, but that's another thing you have to flatten. A regular LCD would be easier.

The self-rewriting magstrip is a serious problem; you might be able to emulate it with a magnetic loop that varies at the right rate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Wasn't sure if I'd get anyone to answer. I'm definitely a quick learner and tinkerer, but this is definitely outside my scope/comfort zone. Where would I even start to try and lay out a schematic, or even to work out the kinks on paper to get an idea if this is even possible?

Comment: I think if you can build a working magstripe emulator on the bench (size & power irrelevant), then you can start adding Bluetooth and displays and shrinking it down. That's amenable to tinkering and a bit of research.